# Can we integrate Extent reports with Qmetry Automation Framework(QAF)?

Tags: java, appium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report, qaf

Can we integrate Extent reports(specifically using Adapters, TestNG or Cucumber)with Qmetry Automation Framework(QAF)? If Yes, please provide the steps.
From my end, I tried what is mentioned here: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/testng.html
And I am not seeing any reports being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is : YES.
In Qmetry Automation Framework(QAF) we can integrate Extent reports.

I'll provide the HOW TO steps in my next update.

Edit / Update:
Create a class as below:

```
public class ExtentReporter implements IReporter {
private ExtentReports extent;

@Override
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
    extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ExtentReport.html", true);
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults();

        for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
            ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();
            try {
                buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), LogStatus.PASS);
                buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), LogStatus.FAIL);
                buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), LogStatus.SKIP);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}

private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, LogStatus status) throws IOException {
    ExtentTest test;

    if (tests.size() > 0) {
        for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
            test = extent.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());

            test.getTest().setStartedTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
            test.getTest().setEndedTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));

            for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                test.assignCategory(group);

            String message = "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed";

            if (result.getThrowable() != null)
                message = result.getThrowable().getMessage();

            test.log(status, message);
            extent.endTest(test);
        }
    }
}

private Date getTime(long millis) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

}

While running you suite or .xml file, add the above class as listener.

```
    <listeners>
    <listener class-name="YOUR.LOCATION.ExtentReporter" />
</listeners>
```

Comment: It really would have help the questioner if you could have provided something more than just the "YES".

Comment: I agree with Darius X!  Thanks Rohith, actually I had completely forgot about this question which I had posted long back. Of course at this point of time we have a solution too! I just want you to take credit for the answer.

Comment: Hey @DariusX. 
Of course, it would be helpful for sure but I have to make sure that it works, so took my time to confirm that it works.

Comment: @Vishwathma I hope this helped you. I really wanted to see the solution that you got. Please do share.